# Origin of the word: "dock"

Tags: etymology

While watching [this video](https://youtu.be/B_CDeYrqxjQ) about which is the correct plural of the word 'Prometheus', I realized that some of the cutting edge technologies like:

- [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) (from: Προμηθεύς)
- [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) (from: Κυβερνήτης)

use names related to greek. So, I wondered if also [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) has any "greek" roots. (To say the truth, I thought of the word: *`Δοκός`*)

According to this site: http://ewonago.blogspot.gr/2008/06/dock.html, `dock` is related to the verb `Δέχομαι` which means: *receive, contain*.

Comment: To be clear, you're asking about the origin of *dock* in the sense meaning ["ship platform"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dock#Noun_3), not any of the other three unrelated senses, correct?

Comment: The *OED* writes that its origins beyond Dutch and English are uncertain.  It does mention Greek *δοχή* "receptacle."  I doubt that whoever named "Docker" was thinking about that, however.  [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dock) is a good starting point for researching etymology questions.